# Specifying pubDate for previous RSS Feed Items

Tags: xml, rss

I'm new to manually creating an rss feed and don't know a whole lot about timezones either.

I have some thing I added to my new feed.xml and backdated (or at least attempted for format it right) for some items I had listed on my website.  So here is an example pubDate in my feed:

```
<pubDate>Tues, 23 Aug 2016 10:00:00 CST</pubDate>
```

I'm Chicago time.  I'm not sure if CST is right here, or what.  The timezone is what I'm grey about here.  Since I'm not using any code to generate this timestamp, how do I know I've got this right if I'm hard coding it like this for backdating stuff for a new feed.xml I create?

would I need something like `-0500` in place of the `CST`?  Is CST there even valid?

Answer (score 0):

pubDate must be an [RFC-822 date-time](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html), so this is valid:

```
<pubDate>Tue, 23 Aug 2016 10:00:00 CST</pubDate>
```

I changed your format a little for it to be ok. You can validate your feed using the [W3C feed validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/)